# Merge CSV files using macro

Tags: excel, csv

Any idea how to merge *.csv files from one folder?

I have many *.csv files with same structure (count & heading of columns) and I need to merge their content into one sheet.

It's not so hard, I know. But When I add content from one table, I need to add new column with name of table where I copied this data from.

Any help please?

Thank you!

Comment: This would be much easier in Python although im assuming you are only wanting to do this with VBA?

Comment: Considering you would first have to install Python, I don't think it would be that much easier. When all you have is a hammer everything looks like a nail. Consider the simplicity in the answer from  @Kevin...

Comment: I have to do this in VBA, thats the problem. This must be simply "tool" for business user.

Comment: I suggest you add this VBA consrtaint to the question and add a VBA tag. It seems this is a key requirement that you did not mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good aproach how to solve this. It merge content of all csv files and delete headers from 2nd file! :) But still need to solve that problem with adding name of source file.

Option Explicit

Sub ImportCSV()

```
Dim strSourcePath As String
Dim strDestPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strData As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Change the path to the source folder accordingly
strSourcePath = "C:\Path\"

If Right(strSourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then strSourcePath = strSourcePath & "\"

'Change the path to the destination folder accordingly
strDestPath = "C:\Path\"

If Right(strDestPath, 1) <> "\" Then strDestPath = strDestPath & "\"

strFile = Dir(strSourcePath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Cnt = Cnt + 1
    If Cnt = 1 Then
       r = 1
   Else
       r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End If
    Open strSourcePath & strFile For Input As #1
        If Cnt > 1 Then
           Line Input #1, strData
       End If
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, strData
            x = Split(strData, ",")
            For c = 0 To UBound(x)
                Cells(r, c + 1).Value = Trim(x(c))
            Next c
            r = r + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
    Name strSourcePath & strFile As strDestPath & strFile
    strFile = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

If Cnt = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "No CSV files were found...", vbExclamation
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for your solution but how can I merge csv files if they include line break /carriage return (CR)/? Some of them include double quotes ("") too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to approach it (ex: [SO 39045638](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045638/vba-code-to-consolidate-csv-data/39046679#39046679))

I personally use a .bat file similar to the below, where loc is the directory for the csv files. This doesn't handle deleting the Aggregate file, though. Nor does it handle repeated headers, so you would need to edit the final csv to remove them.

```
@ECHO OFF  
Set loc=C:\Test\
Copy %loc%*.csv %loc%\Aggregate.csv
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, I agree with you. I did it in same way, but start bat file seems to be difficult for business users :) So it must be one macro for whole operation.

Comment: In what way is double clicking a bat file more difficult than running a macro? Please be specific, this allows use to understand all the constraints before posing an answer