# Importing all workbooks from a folder (VBA - Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to import all the workbooks from this folder into the active sheet. (Path is in the code).

So far my code is this:

```
Option Explicit


Sub load_all_from_folder()
Dim idx As Integer
Dim fpath As String
Dim fname As String

idx = 0
fpath = "/Users/charliekeegan/Desktop/Tester1/"
fname = Dir(fpath & "*.csv")
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    idx = idx + 1
    Sheets("Sheet" & idx).Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
      & fpath & fname, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .Name = "a" & idx
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        fname = Dir
    End With
Wend
End Sub
```

The macro runs but nothing happens in my active sheet - can you see the problem?

Also do you know how i can delete all the sheets after they have been uploaded?

Comment: Import all workbooks into a single sheet? Can you explain a little more? Do you mean combine all the sheets from those csv files into the activeworkbook? In one sheet? All sheets separately?

Comment: Is that `fpath` value right? No drive letter? `/` instead of ` \ ` ? Other than that, the code works for me.

Comment: Is this potentially then the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126116/merge-csv-files-using-macro Or have a look at these that are returned https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=NKQrW7_pHcPHgAaKsY7ICA&q=stackoverflow+vba+combine+csvs&oq=stackoverflow+vba+combine+csvs&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3243.3739.0.4472.4.4.0.0.0.0.202.471.0j2j1.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.MBu38abb0xw

Comment: im on a mac so there is no drive, i have tried to use / and \ with no luck.

That merging .csv code is very complicated @QHarr so i dont want to use it.

Comment: The mac bit and Excel version is an important item to mention in your question!

Comment: Ron De Bruin is usually helpful for this https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=gqorW-2xLMbLgAaR2ZjgDA&q=ron+de+bruin+merging+csvs+mac&oq=ron+de+bruin+merging+csvs+mac&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12168.13640.0.13989.12.11.0.0.0.0.189.1094.2j6.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..6.0.0....0.-q7VgLU1IRw

Comment: @QHarr yes the other people will also be using macs. 

What does that mean for the code?
- can make it work if i use the file path for just one file. but as soon as i want to include a dynamic filepath so i can select everything in a folder, it doesnt work. It runs the macro but nothing happens.

Comment: Any solution would need to be tailored to Mac so important that this is noted. There are some key differences for Macs which Ron De Bruin covers. I have added the Mac-VBA tag so others can see it is for Mac.