# How can I merge or read csv files with line breaks / carriage return (CR) in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, line-breaks

I used very easy and practical solution from [Merge CSV files using macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126116/merge-csv-files-using-macro) which reads and merges CSV files with `Line` command. The problem occurs if some CSV files include break lines (carriage return) then `Line` command reads this data into separate lines not into one.

CSV data in Excel looks like:

[image: CSV data with break lines (carriage return)]

Data in .CSV file looks like:

`Name;Surname;Book Title
Jan;Zitniak;"Microsoft Excel 2019 
for beginners and intermediates"
Tiya;Solomon;"Be happy every day 
in your life!"
Ianis;Tillman;"Honor and the 
Noble Heart"`

Notice: In my .CSV I use semicolon instead comma as separator. Please notice double quotes in data with break lines.

.CSV file to download [here](https://www.janzitniak.info/forum/csv-with-carriage-return.csv).

EDIT:

Another .CSV file with updated data to download [here](https://www.janzitniak.info/forum/csv-with-carriage-return-no-space.csv). Try this data please.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Character in the middle of your double quotes, is that a CR or CRLF? also, character at the end of each "line", is that the same as what you have in your double quotes?

Comment: @Zac - in my post is possible to download that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the interim line feeds to a placeholder character and import the text file. Change the placeholder back to a line feed after it has been opened.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim ff As Integer, str As String, fname As String

    fname = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Downloads\csv-with-carriage-return.csv"

    ff = FreeFile
    Open fname For Input As ff
    str = Input(LOF(ff), ff)
    Close ff

    str = Replace(str, Chr(32) & Chr(13) & Chr(10), Chr(124))

    ff = FreeFile
    Open fname For Output As ff
    Print #ff, str
    Close ff

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fname, Origin:=65001, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                       Semicolon:=True, Tab:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2))

    With ActiveWorkbook

        .Worksheets(1).Columns(3).Cells.Replace what:=Chr(124), replacement:=Chr(32) & Chr(10)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. For my .CSV your code works very well. But. What about data if is no space between text and carriage line and linefeed? If I remove Chr(32) in your code it merges all into one line.  I need remove all Chr(13) & Chr(10) in text in double quotes only.